# Could not access KVM kernel

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, qemu, scons, kvm

The error I get:

```
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
qemu-system-i386 -smp 4 -m 256 -enable-kvm -M pc,kernel_irqchip=off -cdrom build/intel/pc/boot.iso -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=monitor.dev,server,nowait -monitor chardev:charmonitor -nographic
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
qemu-system-i386: failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
scons: *** [qemu] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I am trying to run FreeNOS on Oracle VirtualBox and getting this error.

Comment: You'll need to share your SConstruct/SConscripts and why you are trying to have scons run qemu..

Comment: So you're already in a virtualbox machine and trying to run qemu inside that?

Comment: Virtualbox doesn't support nested virtualization - that is, you can't run kvm inside a vbox guest.  However: why is your sconscript even attempting to do this?

Comment: Okay, I take that partly back, it looks like these days it supports at least some form of nested virt (since 6.1.4 apparently), but you have to enable it explicitly in the guest.  Not sure if that's sufficient for kvm, which needs to see a very specific setting in the "bios".